# Replace Integers in Code except formular values

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-ui, replace

I have a created a sortable with jQueryUI and after sorting I want to replace all integers in this code block with an other integer, except the integers in textarea, input and other form values. This is what I have:

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.item.parent().find('li').each(function(index) {
            var new_html = $(this).html().replace(/\d+/g, (index + 1)).replace(/\d+/, (index + 2));
            $(this).html(new_html);
        });
    }
});
```

Help is greatly appreciated. Best regards, .wired

Comment: As in the form elements also can be entered HTML I think a regex is not bulletproof enough, so I would have to exclude the values first, replace the integers and then stick the parts together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/#expr)

```
var tagsToReplace = $(this).children().not("input, textarea");
tagsToReplace.each(function(index) {
  $(this).html() = $(this).html().replace(/\d+/g, (index + 1)).replace(/\d+/, (index + 2));
}
```